# Compile Groovy files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin

My java web project includes some Groovy code. But eclipse is not recognizing Groovy files and not generating any classes out of it.

I have installed Groovy plugin in Eclipse. Installed Groovy in my windows machine and setup GROOVY_HOME and include groovyall jar file in my lib folder. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts), when the dashboard opens up click on the "extensions" tab and click on the Groovy language feature and install it. Then right click on project, -> Spring -> configure groovy nature to use groovy also.

Another option is create a new Groovy project, the upshot is that you can use any java file within a groovy project since they are so well coupled.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have resolved it by installing the groovy and setting GROOVY_HOME and adding an eclipse groovy plugin to it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you converted your project into a groovy project?  In order for groovy files to be compiled, they must be in a groovy project.  Select Project, right-click -> Configure -> Convert to Groovy Project...

This will set up the groovy dependencies correctly.  You can remove the groovy-all jar from your lib folder.

Comment: It's a J2EE project where I am using Groovy for specific functionality. Converting the whole project to Groovy Project would not be a good idea.