# Eclipse is not compiling my Groovy files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

I'm using Eclipse and working on a J2EE project. We are trying to write Groovy/Spock tests for unit testing. The project is a Maven project and added Groovy nature to it. The problem is *If I edit any of the Groovy test classes, It's doesn't get compiled*. So running a test as Junit is not picking up the latest changes. I have to run a Maven build in order to pickup the recent changes test class.

My setup,

- Groovy compiler 2.4
- Installed Groovy-Eclipse plugin
- Added Groovy nature to the project

Checked another question, it didn't help much
[Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433553/compile-groovy-files-in-eclipse)

Comment: is your code in a source folder?

Comment: @Reimeus, code is in src/main/test. I even added this path to Preferences > Groovy > compiler > Groovy script Folders

Comment: @Reimeus, Sorry exact path of the tests are under src/test/java

Comment: @Siva - why are you not using src/test/groovy for your path?

Comment: @DaveG, We are using both Junit and Groovy tests. So they both living under /src/test/java.

Comment: And does it work if you put your Java and groovy tests under `/src/test/groovy`?

Answer (score 1):

Un checked, the following fixed the issue.

> Preferences > Groovy > compiler > Enable script Folder support